# Difference between грусть, печаль, тоска?

Tags: словоупотребление, узус, лексикон

When to use one or the other, and in wich context?

Comment: Excellent question, definitely +1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's broaden your set of dark and depressive feelings.

**[Грусть](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)** ≈ sadness. The shortest and the lightest. May be caused by bad weather or a sad film/song/book.

> Мне грустно от этой книги.
>
> Серое осеннее небо навеяло на него грусть.

**[Тоска](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)** ≈ melancholy, depression. May be caused by a separation with someone or something.

> Я тоскую по любимой.
>
> Его съедала тоска по родине.

**[Уныние](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)** ≈ despondency, dejection, melancholy. Can be result of *грусть*,*тоска*,*печаль*. Characterized by ultimate lack of motivation. May be caused or result in apathy.

> Не впадай в уныние - все еще можно исправить.
>
> Хватит унывать - начни что-нибудь менять!

**[Печаль](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C)** ≈ grief, sorrow. Somewhere between *грусть*,*тоска*,*уныние*.

> Печально видеть результаты ваших ссор.
>
> Он бы опечален грустной вестью.

**[Скорбь](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%8C)** ≈ sorrow, grief. In most cases is caused by a loss of a close person.

> Он был удивительно светлым человеком, я скорблю вместе с вами.

Comment: I should add that "Уныние" is also a Russian (church) canonical term for a one of seven deadly sins http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acedia

Comment: So, let's say someone loses a leg or contracts cancer or, dare I say it ... comes down with COVID-19?  Which is the best word to use in a phrase such as "It's sad."  And along this line of thinking, I would assume the word to use for someone with a mild case of COVID-19 would be different than for someone who is just barely hanging in there with an intubator ... right?  Likewise, would different words be used for someone who lost a leg versus someone who just merely broke a leg?

Answer (score 3):

Although the dictionaries can write about some minor differencies, all these words are very close synonyms. Consider the following excerpts from Pushkin:

> Князь печально отвечает:
>   "Грусть-тоска меня съедает..."
>
> Мне грустно и легко; печаль моя светла;
>   Печаль моя полна тобою

In my opinion грусть is indefinite, печаль - some bad feeling implied by objective circumstances (from печа = care), and тоска - feeling lonely, missing for smth. Although the dictionaries seem to insist on another meanings.

Comment: there is no such word as печа in russian language. Probably, you meant "опекать", "печься" (о ком-то)

Comment: @Burundanga Almost never used but exists. http://dal.sci-lib.com/word025750.html